# Undefined is not a constructor Jasmine Enzyme Karma

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, enzyme

Hey I have been working in the configuration of karma + jasmine + enzyme to start working in the unit tests of my project, then at exec my first test I got this error

`TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '(0, _jasmine.expect)(addLoan.length)') in src/app/modules/Login/LoginComponent.spec.js (line 80581)
        src/app/modules/Login/LoginComponent.spec.js:80581:29
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17`

then here is my test code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'jasmine';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ServicerComponent from './LoginComponent';

function setup() {
    const props = {
        error: {},
        onClick: () => {},
        emailOnChange: () => {},
        passwordOnChange: () => {},
    };

    return shallow(<ServicerComponent{...props} />);
}

describe('<ServicerComponent />', () => {
    const displayNames = {
        login: 'login',
    };
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = setup();
    });

    it('should have a Login button', () => {
        const addLoan = wrapper.find({ name: displayNames.login });

        expect(addLoan.length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

also I am using :
jasmine: 2.5.3
enzyme: 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to create setup instance of the class

```
beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = new setup();
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but there is not the solution :c

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer of the question, I just remove the jasmine importer and add a global variable in the `.eslintrc.json` named `expect` equal `true`